# We are planning on building a desktop based e-mail client in C#. What are the challenges that we might face during this? (we are new to this platform)

Tags: c#, client, desktop-application, email

we are planning to build a desktop based e-mail client using C#. As we are new to this platform and technology, can anyone enlighten us with the problems that we might face during this process?

Comment: I can't even think about how to start answering this. You'll face huge challenges. Or none at all. It all depends on where you're starting and what you're comparing it to.  But for starters, I'm not sure it's terribly wise to start such an ambitious project on a platform that's so new to your team that this is the sort of question you have to ask.

Comment: Closing this question here.

Comment: Normally I think people are too quick to close questions. This is a good example of a question that *should* be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be anything particularly problematic about building such a client, except the learning of the platform and tools itself, of course.

The only problem I know of now has to do with connecting to MS Exchange in an elegant way.
But SMTP and POP3 protocols should be no problem.